# Minimum signal length for notch filter?

Tags: filters, filter-design

I'm back again with another probably very basic question, but I searched a lot about the minimum length of signal for a filter to work, and mine seems to satisfy this (from filtfilt requirement in MATLAB), but still the filter doesn't seem to work. Please help.

Context : Dealing with an encoder signal for angular velocity measurements. The measurement is noisy due to 2 reasons : Eccentricity error of encoder (has a period equal to one revolution), and other errors (position error, state width error etc, which I assume as random). I have tried to remove the influence of random errors by averaging "n" samples, to get a new signal which seems to have worked in cancelling the high frequency noise (after lowpass filtering). However, the eccentricity error still remains.

What I did : I am trying to remove the influence of eccentricity error with a notch filter. I have calculated the mean rotational speed, and used the "irrnotch" function in MATLAB to generate a notch filter.

Problem : Even after applying the notch filter (using filtfilt), that frequency doesn't seem to be attenuated. I only have one rotation worth of data (signal length corresponds to one rotation), and I am trying to cancel out the fundamental frequency (with the period equal to one rotation). How can I proceed with this ? Is the notch filter not working because I have only one rotation worth of data?

I have put some figures below:

The input to the filter is yellow, which is the average angular speed signal. Output from the filter is purple.

[image: input and filtered signal]

FVtool from MATLAB. sampling freq for the yellow signal is close to 3.5 Hz (after averaging). cutoff frequency that I need removed is 0.177 Hz. So I input 0.1 as the normalised frequency.

[image: FVtool of notch filter]

I understand in this particular case, there is not much variation in the input signal except the effect of the eccentricity error, and I should probably take the mean and call it a day, but I want to know what I can do if there were higher variations super imposed on the base signal. How should I filter the base signal out ? Should I highpass, and add the mean back? or any other way..

Comment: Are you sure the frequency you need removed is at 0.177Hz?

Comment: I double checked now. The theory is that the eccentricity occurs at the angular frequency of rotation. But I understand that angular frequency won't exactly be constant over time. Since eccentricity effects occur over one full rotation of the encoder, I am using the average angular frequency over the whole rotation as the notch frequency. Average angular frequency is the mean of the yellow curve (10.6334 rpm) so notch freq is (10.6334/60 = 0.17722 Hz)

Comment: Your notch filter is fixed. If the frequency deviates even a little from the notch center, it's not going to be attenuated as much.

Comment: But I am using the calculated value as input to design the notch filter in Matlab. I mentioned 0.177 Hz to not type out the full number. Like in the iirnotch function I input the normalised freq as (mean of yellow signal/60)/(fsamp/2).

Comment: Is there a minimum length of signal needed for a filter to work correctly..or is there something happeing when the notch freq is so close to the fundamental FFT frequency ? My only reference is in the "filtfilt" documentation, they say signal should be 3 times the order. I checked the [b, a] of "iirnotch" and both have 3 values each, so it will be 9 sampled minimum..I have 20 samples.

Comment: I get that part, but as you mentioned,  the frequency of interest **isn’t constant in time**. Your filter notches at one **fixed** frequency, so if the signal has a component that deviates from that frequency, it will sometimes be notched, sometimes not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144354/discussion-between-jdip-and-s-holmes).

Comment: Could you describe this where the frequencies of interest are all in Hz?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to preserve all frequencies other than 0.177 Hz and 2*0.177 Hz. The sampling frequency is around 3.5 Hz. With Jdip's answer, I widened the notch -3db bandwidth and it seems to work. I don't exactly know what frequency to cancel, since that depends on the angular speed, which I am trying to measure in the first place. I think its kind of a cyclic problem. But since it will be "around" the mean value, increasing the bandwidth seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call the frequency of interest $f_0$. You mention $f_0$ isn't constant in time, so it deviates by a certain amount. Let's call that amount $f_1$, so that the actual frequency of interest $f_n \in \left[f_0-f_1, f_0+f_1\right]$

You either need:

- An adaptive notch filter that can track $f_n$
- A wider notch filter, i.e a band-stop filter with cut-offs based on how much $f_0$ deviates (i.e. based on $f_1$).

However, if the only component you care about below $f_n$ is DC, then go ahead and use a high-pass filter with cut-off $<f_0-f_1$, and add DC back after filtering.

Comment: Thankyou! I tried with a higher -3db bandwidth and it looks better. I cannot see a full wave anymore.